# Can't map drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-connection, rpc

I have seven computers with Windows 7 Professional, three computers having problems. When you want to make drive C or D (Windows 7 Professional edition clients) become mapped network drives for a remote user (Windows 7 Ultimate), then it should show the security windows, prompting to enter the password for network client 1.

When I enter the correct username and password, the client is not letting me access the C or D drive when Windows security reappears. Firewall is off, RPC is enabled, and remote desktop is on. The antivirus allows networking.

- If you enter a username and password for this Windows 7 Professional client directly on the computer, it works.
- Windows 7 Professional clients other than the four computers do not experience the same problem
- Again and again I checked the settings on four computers, the settings remain the same but the results are different.

Question:

1. Which client settings do I have to make to get this functionality working again?
2. Is there a difference between the facilities Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate offer with regards to remote drive?

Answer (score 0):

One method for enabling the `[drive_letter]$` shares is as follows (do this on the machines whose admin shares you want to access):

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
   ```
3. If the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry entry does not exist, follow these steps:

   1. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
   2. Type `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`, and then press ENTER.
4. Right-click `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`, then click Modify.
5. In the Value data box, type 1, and click OK.
6. Exit Registry Editor.

This is from [Microsoft KB951016](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016)